# Why can't I deploy a Wpf application in a production server? Problems about "Trust not granted"

Tags: c#, .net

I am deploying a WPF application, in my local computer its works fine but when I deploy in a production server I have an error `"Trust not granted"`. I changed of certificate and I set all of a recommendations in Stack Overflow suggestions buy I have no permissions in my IE to run of application.

In production server I set the truth level in full(Internal), but it is not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem following this link:

[how-to-run-wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/maxim/2008/03/05/how-to-run-wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application/)

Be sure Import certificate file from "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" tab
and from "Trusted Publishers" tab

The application just can be opened with Internet Explorer, using another browser we must copy dlls and make some changes that not apply to this question